# Is QuickReports included with Delphi 2009?

Tags: delphi, delphi-2009, quickreports

We are considering moving from Delphi 7 to Delphi 2009 and would like to know if QuickReports is still included in the package?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is not included with Delphi 2009, it is replaced with RaveReports. You have to purchase.

Answer (score 2):

The last version which came with Quick Reports was D7, and QR was not installed as default (since it was the first version with Rave) - but included on the Demos folder. Since then, you have to purchase it.
EDIT: As Gerry said, in the D2006 registered users' downloads, there's a Qr4Standard available.